# Deduce an inequality from the continuity of power function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $p\in[0,1]$, and $a_n\gt 0$ for $n\in \Bbb {N} $，we have:
$$ a_1^p + \dots + a_N^p \ge \{ a_1 + \dots + a_N \}^p $$
as the condition.

My question is how to deduce the following inequality:
$$ \sum_{n \in \Bbb {N} } a_i^p \ge  \ ( \sum_{n \in \Bbb {N} } a_i \ )^p $$
from the continuity of power function.

Answer (score 2):

Let $s=\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } a_n , s_n =\sum_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n } a_n$ and $f:\mathbb{R}_+ \to\mathbb{R}_+ $, $f(u) =u^p$ then by the continuity of $f$ we have $$\left(\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } a_n\right)^p = f(s) =f(\lim_{n\to\infty } s_n )=\lim_{n\to\infty } f(s_n ) \leqslant \lim_{n\to \infty }\sum_{1\leqslant k\leqslant n } a_n^p = \sum_{n\in\mathbb{N} } a_n^p .$$

Comment: @CalvinLin no it isnt. The OP stated $f(s_n) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{n} a_{k}^{p}$ as an assumption. There is a typo in there though (It should be $a_{k}^{p}$ in the sum)

Comment: @user159517 Thanks. I misunderstood the question.